# Split git diff --name-status by line break

Tags: git, bash, git-bash

I'm trying to export a list of changed files from two commits with git, with this command:

```
read -ra ADDR <<< `git diff --name-only HEAD..HEAD~1 | sed -e "s/ /\\\ /g"`
for i in "${ADDR[@]}"; do 
    echo "$i"
done
```

This works fine. I get a nice list printed out to the terminal with each file on a new row.

```
file1.txt
file2.txt
file3.txt
```

However, I want to use `--name-status` instead of `--name-only`. The reason is so I can later do different things depending on what kind of change was made (e.g. M or D).

This doesn't work though. I get a list in the following format:

```
M
file1.txt
M
file2.txt
M
file3.txt
```

I have tried to changed the `IFS` variable to `$'\n'` (returns everything on one row), `$'\t'` (returns first row, e.g. `M file1.txt`) and `' '` (same as `\t`) without success.

Comment: can you just add ';/^M$/d' to your sed script to delete the lines that are just M. Good luck.

Comment: When I run `git diff --name-status <com1>..<com2>` I get a  list of file names, with the status in the first column. I'm not sure what your `sed` command is offering you. My bash is not the best, so I can't give an example, but I think you can get what you want with `awk`, which will let you grab fields by position, and output them. http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/01/awk-introduction-tutorial-7-awk-print-examples/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
while read STATUS ADDR
do
    echo "$ADDR ($STATUS)"
done  < <(git diff --name-status HEAD..HEAD~1)
```

E.g. for git output like

```
M       INSTALL
M       debian/changelog
M       src/lib/libnvpair/SConscript
M       src/lib/libzfscommon/SConscript
M       src/lib/libzpool/SConscript
M       src/zfs-fuse/main.c
```

the following is printed by the while loop:

```
INSTALL (M)
debian/changelog (M)
src/lib/libnvpair/SConscript (M)
src/lib/libzfscommon/SConscript (M)
src/lib/libzpool/SConscript (M)
src/zfs-fuse/main.c (M)
```