# Gitolite Configure post-push hook and perform operation on committed content

Tags: gitolite, gitosis

I am using the Gitolite to create the git repo.

I have requirement that when user push  something to repo it must have some specific file (eg. `.md` file) otherwise don't let push the code.

So now I need to configure a post-push hook and do some operation on pushed content.

Can any one please help me to do the same?

Answer (score 0):

First, I would not recommend [gitosis (old and obsolete)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10888358/6309).

Second, this is a job for a [`VREF`](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/vref.html) ([update hooks](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/vref.html#mimicking-a-plain-old-update-hook) in Gitolite lingo).
You can use in that `VREF` a [`diff --name-only` or `diff --name-status`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8743741/6309):

```
 git diff --name-only <sha-old> <sha-new>
```

(See [shell explained](http://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=git%20diff%20--name-only%20sha-old%20sha-new))

If the list doesn't include your `.md` file, you would exit with a non-zero status, and the `git push` would be denied.